# Foundation 6 dropdown menu too wide

Tags: css, zurb-foundation-6

I can't decrease the width on the submenus. I tried setting explicit widths, that didn't help. [Here is a screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myddd.png)

Please help!

Comment: set max-width:100%; on the dropdown and give a try

Comment: @ChandraShekhar that did not work :(

Comment: fiddle the code at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I found the solution. The rule min-width: 200px must be overriden in the .is-dropdown-submenu class